# Align button and image vertically

Tags: html, css

I wanted to align button and Image vertically in center, right now button is showing on top of line, I am using bootstrap, can anyone help?

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-5" style="margin-left: -37px;"><p class="imageSveMsg" style="display:none">Save</p><button style="display:none" fieldid="81" class="saveimgbtn fileUpload btn btn-primary">Save Image</button>
<div class="fileUpload hideFileUpload btn btn-primary">  <span class="chooseimagetext"><b>Change Image</b></span><input rowid="submission_81" id="uploadImage" onchange="PreviewImage();" tabindex="13" type="file" name="matrix_submission_data81" accept="image/png, image/jpeg , image/jpeg" class="upload   matrix_submission_draft  "> 
 </div></div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
<input type="hidden" name="oldmatrix_submission_data81" value="16440505543.png"><img id="uploadPreview" src="https://staging-reconresearchlive.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/plugins/matrix-engine/includes/submission_images/16440505543.png" width="50px !important;" height="50px !important;" style="margin-left:30px;max-width: 200px;max-height: 100px;min-height: 100px;vertical-align: middle !important;"></div></div>
```

css:

```
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #E2A169 !important;
    border-color: #E2A169 !important;
}
img{
margin-left: 30px;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

Output:
[Current Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqe8d.png)

Comment: You can use `align-items: center`

Comment: @SaikatRoy thanks for quick answer, but it's not working.

Comment: It's working here. take a look https://codepen.io/njmsaikat/pen/wvPoZPm

Answer (score 1):

You can use `align-items: center`

Please check fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zc5axdnr/1/

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
   
</head>
  
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="align-items: center;">
          <div class="col-6">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec lorem eu leo interdum mollis at quis ligula. Sed pharetra ante metus, sed fermentum diam efficitur vitae. Pellentesque ac porttitor nunc. Mauris lacus quam, facilisis sed congue vulputate, aliquam nec nibh. Maecenas et nulla lacus. Fusce commodo egestas mauris, ut viverra sapien cursus id. Morbi cursus tristique posuere. Pellentesque tincidunt nulla id commodo fermentum. Phasellus sit amet imperdiet orci, eget cursus ipsum. Duis quis metus nunc. Curabitur ex ipsum, suscipit non erat sit amet, lacinia pharetra mi.

Ut vel velit ante. Duis facilisis nisi in sapien posuere gravida. Proin mollis nibh tellus, vitae sodales purus tincidunt eget. Praesent a ullamcorper justo. Integer mollis porttitor sem. Pellentesque vulputate et justo eget blandit. Praesent non lacus mauris. Nam urna ligula, interdum egestas dictum quis, hendrerit pulvinar lorem. Quisque varius eros felis, a dapibus leo consequat eget. Nulla laoreet eros dui, laoreet laoreet libero cursus ullamcorper. Suspendisse hendrerit consequat purus, vel tincidunt risus blandit sed. Nulla mattis laoreet urna quis blandit. Donec et odio facilisis metus congue dictum rhoncus eget turpis. Suspendisse aliquet sit amet ligula quis pellentesque. Cras ullamcorper nec magna id aliquam.



          </div>
          <div class="col-6 align-items-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
            Button
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu Before commenting please check output. It's vertical not horizontal.

Comment: Ohh man!! So here button is vertically center to the text.

Comment: that's right,sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing the first div elements class to `<div class="row align-items-center">` instead of `<div class="col-md-12">`